# "Upload to OneDrive" option not present in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, onedrive, microsoft-outlook-2016

I want to setup Outlook 2016 with the option to specify that an attachment should be uploaded to OneDrive with the "Upload to OneDrive" option as described [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Attach-a-file-to-an-email-in-Outlook-for-Windows-bdfafef5-792a-42b1-9a7b-84512d7de7fc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

Or like this:

[image: Upload to OneDrive]

The Office365 account is specified in Outlook, and that shows some functionnality ("Attach File" has the "Browse Web Locations -> OneDrive" option), but I'm still not seeing Upload to OneDrive. How can I configure it?

Note: The computer is part of a domain.